# Java Eclipse - Exporting issue

Tags: java, eclipse

I have currently finished my java project in eclipse and now I would like to export it as an executable .jar. The strange thing is, that my program is working fine, when I run it in eclipse, but, unfortnuately, it is not working when I export it. 
What should happen:
Well, I have set up a GlobalMouseListener with system-hook-2.5.jar. When I run it as an executable .jar I don't get any input from the listener. 
Library is included (I'm working with system-hook-2.5.jar). Is this a problem? It is not the first time exporting a Java Project for me.

Any suggestions, what I could try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always a good idea to start the program via console
Type in

```
java -jar <Filename>
```

I got an exception, that causes some problems.